# Connect static agents to dynamic jenkins (Jenkins running in OpenShift)

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-agent

We are running Jenkins in Open-shift and its fully up and running. Now, when trying to add a static agents we are getting the 404 not found error.

Agent startup script:

```
java -jar remoting_dslave.jar -jnlpUrl http://xxx-xxx-xxx.apps.ocp1.uat.dbs.com/computer/xxxxxxxx2a/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -workDir "/dcifent/JenkinsSlaves/ci3_dynamicSlave"
```

Getting the below error:

```
WARNING: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Jun 07, 2022 11:17:23 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: http:/xxxxxxxxx.apps.ocp1.uat.dbs.com/ provided port:8080 is not reachable
java.io.IOException: http://xxxxxxxxx.apps.ocp1.uat.dbs.com/ provided port:8080 is not reachable
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:311)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:689)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:514)
```

Creted new router in OpenShift for port 8080 updated the startup script as below

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://routefor8080.apps.ocp1.uat.dbs.com/computer/xxxxxxxx2a/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -workDir "/dcifent/JenkinsSlaves/ci3_dynamicSlave"
```

Getting the different error now.

```
Failed to obtain http://routefor8080.apps.ocp1.uat.dbs.com/computer/xxxxxxxx2a/jenkins-agent.jnlp?encrypt=true
java.io.IOException: Failed to load http://routefor8080.apps.ocp1.uat.dbs.com/computer/xxxxxxxx2a/jenkins-agent.jnlp?encrypt=true: 404 Not Found
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.parseJnlpArguments(Launcher.java:517)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:345)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:296)
Waiting 10 seconds before retry
```

How can i connect static agents to dynamic Jenkins, can someone please help?